# Factoring the quintic polynomial $x^5+4x^3+x^2+4=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

I am trying to factor

$$x^5+4x^3+x^2+4=0$$

I've used Ruffini's rule to get

$$(x+1)(x^4-x^3+5x^2-4x+4)=0$$

But I don't know what to do next.

The solution is $(x+1) (x^2+4) (x^2-x+1) = 0$. I've tried using the completing square method but with no result. Could you give me hints?

Comment: Since you know the solution just try to go backwards to the previous step

Comment: Those two terms containing the number $4$ just *beg* to be grouped together and factored, wouldn't you agree ? Then, in the remaining two, $x^2$ is an obvious choice for a common factor. But now we have two groups of terms, each containing $x^3+1$ ! After factoring that, we notice that the remaining quadratic has no real roots, and $x^3+1$ can be factored by realizing that $1=1^3$, and using the fact that $a^3+b^3$$=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would start by factoring $x^3$ out from the first two terms and noticing the pattern in the result.
$$
\begin{split}
x^5+4x^3 + x^2 + 4 &= x^3 \left(x^2+4\right) + x^2+4 \\
                   &= \left(x^2+4\right)\left(x^3+1\right) \\
                   &= \left(x^2+4\right)(x+1)\left(x^2-x+1\right), \\
\end{split}
$$
where the last step is the standard factoring of the sum of two cubes.

Comment: Great! How did you know it? :)

Comment: Very nice! Without such tricks, kroneckers method is necessary to factor a polynomial.

Comment: @Surferonthefall you have to factor many pages of those and you develop intuition :-)

Comment: Look at the coefficients! They are $1,4,1,4$. Sometimes it can get a bit more complicated. For example $2,-3,-6,9 = 2,-3,-3(2), -3(-3)$

Answer (score 5):

Or, alternatively, note that $$x^4-x^3+5x^2-4x+4=x^2(x^2-x+1)+4x^2-4x+4$$ and factor $4$ from the last three terms.

Comment: Is there any motivation for that manipulation (that isn't reverse engineered)?

Comment: @Michael T - Nothing other than learning at an early age (doing lots of integrals and other things) that it sometimes pays to split one term into the sum (or product sometimes) of two terms. Writing the coefficient on $x^2$ as $1+4$ creates a nice sequence of coefficients: 1, -1, 1; 4, -4, 4; and the rest just flows from there. As gt6989b said above, if you do enough of these things, you develop an intuition. Some of these things are as much art as science.

Answer (score 3):

Here I think this will work . Main idea being splitting up of $5x^2$ as $4x^2 + x^2$

$$(x+1)(x^4-x^3+5x^2-4x+4)=0$$
$$(x+1) (x^4-x^3+4x^2+ x^2-4x+4)=0 $$
$$(x+1) (x^4+4x^2+ x^2-x^3-4x+4)=0 $$
$$(x+1)[ x^2(x^2+4)+ (1-x)( x^2 +4)]=0 $$
$$(x+1)[ (x^2+4)(x^2+1-x))=0 $$
$$(x+1)[ (x^2+4)(x^2-x+1))=0 $$

Hence proved

Answer (score 0):

The answers actually
$$
(x^2 + 4)(x^3 + 1)\\
x^5 + 4x^3 + x^2 + 4\\
(x^5 + 4x^3)(x^2 + 4)\\
x^3(x^2 + 4) 1(x^2 + 4)\\
(x^2 + 4)(x^3 + 1)
$$
(Sorry, too lazy to actually change them to exponents)